# powershell replace text between 2 lines

Tags: powershell, replace, lines, between

I have a text file and want to replace the text between 2 lines. This is working OK until there is no text between the two lines.

my code:

```
$File = "D:\test.txt" 
$NewLine = "newline with some text"
$text = Get-Content "D:\test.txt" -raw

$text -replace ('(?m)(.*)^Line 3[\r\n]+Line 4([\r\n])', $NewLine) | 
  Out-File $File -Force
```

### Text files:

Text file that does work:

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3
>   Line 4
>   Line 5
>   Line 6

---

Text file that does NOT work:

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3
>   Some text here
>   Line 4
>   Line 5
>   Line 6

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show what you expect to see from each file _after_ the script runs.

Comment: I would like the outcome to be like this:

    Line 1
    Line 2
    newline with some text    
    Line 5
    Line 6

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1
Can you explain? I am a newbie...

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No, `-raw` doesn't strip new line characters, it just reads the file in as a multi-line string. Run `(gc $file -raw) -match '\r'` and you can see that it will find Carriage Return characters, and you can run it with `'\n'` to see that it finds New Line characters too. I'm also not sure what wrong escapes he's using, that's a valid regular expression that he's using... sloppy, but valid, and it explains why he isn't getting the results that he wants, because his regex doesn't allow for it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `Ignores newline characters and returns the entire contents of a file in one string.` I guess I misunderstood what the help text meant by this. Wouldn't `\`r\`n` be the correct escapes?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Since he's using the `-replace` operator, which utilizes Regular Expression matching, he can use the RegEx reserved characters of `[\r\n]+`. I use that all the time to find the end of a line, whether it be a CR or NL, or both.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician TIL. Cheers.  To the OP's point, your regex is wrong. It doesn't capture characters that happen between Line 3 and Line 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that your Regular Expression (RegEx for short) does not allow for anything between Line 3 and Line 4. Here's what you're using (cleaned up a tiny bit):

```
(?m)^Line 3[\r\n]+Line 4[\r\n]
```

Let us break that down just a little bit. `(?m)` puts the RegEx engine into multi-line mode, so it will allow you to use the carat `^` to indicate the beginning of a line, instead of just the beginning of the string. There's other things it does, but that's what you are using it for. I discarded the `(.*)`, because it is pointless. So you have a carat indicating the beginning of a line, followed by the text `Line 3`, and then `[\r\n]+` which will find the end of the line. Then it finds `Line 4`, immediately followed by the end of that line. This is why it fails when there is text, you didn't allow for any additional text. To do that you can use `.*?`. What that means is this: The dot indicates any character, doesn't matter if it's letter, number, symbol, or even a character that doesn't register on the screen. The asterisk `*` indicates that there needs to be zero or more of that, so zero or more of any character. The question mark tells it to look for zero or more, but to match as few characters as possible before moving on in the pattern, so it will only match things until it can move on to `Line 4[\r\n]`. The functional pattern would be:

```
(?m)^Line 3[\r\n]+.*?[\r\n]Line 4[\r\n]
```

Comment: Thx It works!

I just added (?ms) so it will replace multiple lines.

Comment: What's the purpose of wrapping the line ending in a capture block?  Wouldn't that only catch one or the other? What happens if you have both? Doesn't it fail then?  Or does `Get-Content -Raw` only return newlines in the single string instead of the Windows `\r\n`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't wrap anything in a capture `()`, I use the square brace to indicate that it should match any of the characters, so `[\r\n]` will match on either `\r` or `\n`, and I use a `+` to indicate that it needs one or more of them. I believe that `-raw` returns whatever is coded into the file.

Comment: Wrong terminology but you get what I mean.  You don't use that syntax beyond the first one (`[\r\n]+`), so I'm assuming the following two sets would fail if it is indeed \r\n endings

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Oh! Sorry, I just understood. Nope, this works just fine as is. It looks for at least one of either `\r` or `\n`, we don't really care which, it's just to make sure that `Line 4` is on its own line, and not contained within the text between Line 3 and Line 4. I suppose it's inconsistent, I could just as easily added a `+` after them just like I did the first one, but it really doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected your regex here to capture only Line 3 and Line 4 with the text inbetween.

```
$File = 'D:\test.txt'
$NewLine = 'newline with some text'
$text = Get-Content -Path 'D:\test.txt' -Raw

$Pattern = '(?m)^Line\s3[\r\n]+.*?Line\s4'

$text -replace $Pattern,$NewLine | 
  Out-File -FilePath $File -Force
```